# Is it "greedy" to ask newbies to not forget an upvote if they find the answer useful?

Tags: discussion

You know that it happens quite often that you give a really good and helpful answer, but you never get an upvote or a "correct" mark, or no answer at all. Especially with newbies who don't know the rules.

So today, I decided to help a newbie, and I wrote at the end of my answer: *Please don't forget to upvote this answer if it is useful to you, or mark it as correct, if you feel it was the right answer. Thanks!*

And then, someone with 17k (!) reputation commented: *Good answer. FYI, I was going to upvote until I saw your note at the end.*

**Can you please honestly tell me what you think about that case?** I'm somewhat surprised to see that someone can be such a "scrooge" that he refuses to give away even one of his 40 free (!) upvotes. Even more from someone with that rep, who should know what is going on.

Or do you feel my question is "greedy"? But I just feel like everybody should get "paid" for the work we do here, and therefore I sometimes remember others to do so, especially when I see that they are newbies.

P.S.: I looked through the answers from "uncle scrooge", and I found he gives good answers. I **upvoted** four of them. As you know, I'm an evangelist of upvoting quality posts. I'm not a "people pleaser", but I believe in **paying for work**.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208134/217863

Comment: The OP [of that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31224063/73226) couldn't upvote you anyway at the moment as they don't have enough rep.

Comment: Commenting? Seems a little needy, but broadly acceptable. *Adding it to your answer?* Unacceptable; it doesn't contribute at all to answering the question.

Comment: Begging for rep is considered very *gauche*, equivalent to helping a friend to clean out his basement and asking for payment after the job is done.  A misstep that's "worse" than the friend not saying thank you.  Expect an "are you kidding me??" response.  You can educate a newbie that doesn't know that saying thank you is considered the polite thing to do.  And important, this web site would not work well without the gamification aspect.   Careful phrasing could be: "Sounds like your problem is solved, please close your question by selecting the answer that helped you most".

Comment: Normally, if I get a "thank you, this works" comment from the OP without an upvote/accept, I will comment to let him know this is how it works. But directly in the answer? I concur with "uncle scrooge".

Comment: In my mind, it's 'you win some, you lose some'. I believe the amount of upvotes and accepts we get from other answers balance out the one we don't earn from to be able to call our earnings more of reality.

Answer (score 22):

Well, it incontestably doesn't belong in an answer.

Now, you have looked at their profile, seen they never accepted anything or voted on anything, and you waited a week or so?

Well, then you can ask them with a comment on the question whether *any* of the answers (*don't* restrict it to yours, please) were useful and thus worth an upvote, and whether any of them solved his question for him and should be accepted.
Link to the relevant parts of the help-center, and really try to avoid even the appearance of begging for votes.

Also, avoid suggesting anything they cannot (yet) do, like accepting an answer shortly after posting the question or upvoting while not having enough reputation.

Of course, if there was an unambiguous indication by the OP, you might help him to use the site properly sooner.
If possible, you might even advise on an older question, so they are more likely to look at all their posts and you are less involved as a direct beneficiary.

Answer (score 12):

Personally I don't believe that any sort of comment like that needs to be posted.  It doesn't leave me with a good feeling in that you're asking them, "Hey, if I helped you, be sure to accept my answer so that I get points."  I realize that may not have been your *intent*, but that's how I interpreted it.

There are always going to be people that don't accept an answer, or upvote an answer if it helped them.  It would be slightly different if they said "thank you"; at which point a gentle reminder pointing towards [why "thank you" isn't always how we show our gratitude here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) would be appropriate in a **comment** only.  But, I would strongly discourage anyone from posting something like that in their answer.

Keep your answers focused on the answer; if you need to have a small comment, do so as a comment, but remember that even those are temporal.  The more important part here is that you left an answer, and the community will, with time, determine if it is good.  I see it has a couple of upvotes already<sup>1</sup>, so there's progress.

<sup>1:  Meta effect, likely</sup>