# What should I do about comments were someone asks for their answer to be accepted/up-voted?

Tags: discussion, comments, upvotes

Today I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726216/swift-2-catch-22-with-value-of-optional-type-not-unwrapped#32726235), under one the answers there was a comment asking the OP to mark their answer as accepted, and up-vote it.

> please upvote and accept the answer thx

I this acceptable?

[image]

Comment: related: [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie in SO)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-in)

Comment: You should do...nothing. Flag as noise (too chatty or not constructive) if you want but there's nothing else to be done. Since the OP has obviously asked plenty of questions, and even accepted some, he knows how accepting and upvoting works so the comment is useless. "Acceptable" it shouldn't happen unless the person hasn't asked and/or accepted any answers and you link them to *why* the voting system exists.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298579/is-it-greedy-to-ask-newbies-to-not-forget-an-upvote-if-they-find-the-answer-us

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such comments are noise. Flag them as "not constructive" and we'll clean them up.

Comment: Comments with the word *accept* in them apparently get removed with a single flag. I'm not sure whether moderation involvement is still a part of the end process but they are immediately removed from the common user's view.