# Flagging comments at 20K

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

In accordance with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306646/what-should-i-do-about-comments-were-someone-asks-for-their-answer-to-be-accepte/306650#306650) meta question, I came across a *"If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it <blah>, <blah> ..."* comment and decided to test the predominantly recommended practise of flagging it as "not constructive" then letting the PTB clean things up. If the flag was declined, I figured I could survive one more declined flag and ultimately I would learn something either way.

Boom. The comment was gone.

I didn't think I had that ability so I went back to the [20K privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) and reviewed it. The word **Flag** isn't even on that page but there are two privileges related to deleting questions. A meta site search produced similar results.

- Voting to delete answers with score of -1 or lower
- Voting to delete questions with a score of -3 or lower immediately after they are closed

Fair enough. I can see where those could be applied to comments but here's the rub.

- I cannot see the voting stats on a comment so how do I determine whether my vote is going to have an immediate effect or a delayed one? I would like to know this **before** I transfer a comment to the bit bucket.
- I would have liked to know about this beforehand. If it had been even a footnote in the [20K privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), I would have. I'd like to see an edit or addendum to that end.

These points become more important if I didn't even need a -1 (previous flag ...?) on the comment before committing it to oblivion. The action certainly isn't reversible by anything I could determine. Some clarity on what I can and cannot do at 20K would help.

Comment: The word "accept" is one of the "bad words" of SO. Anyone comment with such a word gets insta-deleted by a single flag.

Comment: "accept" *I like to live dangerously* But yeah not being able to see voting stats on comments can be a hassle

Comment: Thanks @Mysticial - It sounds as if I've just confused two very different aspects of the site. I'll leave the question here for a bit and maybe even delete it if there is little or negative interest as this would seem to fall into almost 'a problem that can no longer be reproduced' category.

Comment: voting stats on comments? there are no downvotes on comments, so the "statistic" is simply "if there is a number, it's upvoted. If there is no number, it's not upvoted.

Comment: @Patrice - I believe I was thinking more along the lines of a count of previous flags much as there are close votes displayed. In any event, the point is moot as I was confusing two very different things.

Comment: [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/165773)

Comment: @Mysticial Last time I checked "accept" is not a "bad word". But "accepting" and "accept rate" are.

Comment: @Jeeped [Comments that are flagged by multiple users are deleted automatically. The number of flags needed is based on the comment's score. It currently takes "3 + (Score / 3)" flags to delete a comment.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757)