# Automatic deletion of comment by non Mod?

Tags: support, flags, comments

I'm obviously not a moderator, nor a user with >10k rep (so have no [moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)), but somehow about 90% of my flags I have cast on comments in the past hour (probably around 30) have caused the comment to get deleted, rather than marked as "waiting for review".

Why is this? How is it possible for me to delete comments based off one single flag?

[image: Flag Gif]

Comment: Side note: your first sentence is wrong, since you got your first [moderation privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation) at 15 rep, when you started upvoting/flagging. Useful to keep in mind that on SE, moderation privileges are pretty pervasive.

Comment: @NathanTuggy noted, changed to "tools" as per the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Comment: @NathanTuggy one can argue that ["most powerful moderation tool is given at really modest rep 5: participate in meta..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268115/839601) :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Accept nagging is annoying, and deleting these comments creates quite a bit of unnecessary work for moderators. So if the comment you're flagging matches a certain pattern common to such comments, it'll be removed instantly.

(This replaces the old pattern that previously matched "accept rate", since accept rate hasn't been a thing for quite a few years now).

This went live last Thursday - credit goes to Jon Ericson for bringing it up, after some mods on English Language & Usage raised the issue with him (they actually *may* have wanted fewer comments to be deleted, but that's just crazy talk).

### Related:

- [Is it "greedy" to ask newbies to not forget an upvote if they find the answer useful?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298579/is-it-greedy-to-ask-newbies-to-not-forget-an-upvote-if-they-find-the-answer-us)
- ["Begging for votes" vs. "Reminding for upvotes" vs. "Reminding for acceptance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208130/begging-for-votes-vs-reminding-for-upvotes-vs-reminding-for-acceptance)
- [Begging for Votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes)

Comment: I can't accept the credit you gave me in this answer.

Comment: @JonEricson: And now to wait for some vandal to come along and flag it….

Comment: @NathanTuggy: I have come to accept that some of my brilliant comments will be deleted. Better to write an answer instead.