# Is it allowed to repeatedly ask the OP to give feedback or accept the answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette

I stumbled upon a question with the following comments, all of which were posted by one user:

[image: comments]

Putting myself in OP's shoes, I would be somewhat annoyed by comments urging me to do what I am not obligated to do over and over again. Therefore, I would have asked the user to stop pestering the OP, or even flagged one of the comments for moderator attention. However, to my surprise, the author of these comments is a newly elected moderator.

According to Meta, it's fine to ask for feedback or explain how does accepting answers work *once*. Doing so multiple times would be unethical and inappropriate, at least in my opinion, but given the example set by a moderator, I'm starting to doubt that.

How should I handle such situations?

Comment: The first two comments seem maybe acceptable to me. The third is where it really goes off-the-rails and sounds rather pathetic. The user who left such comments seems to be in need of an education, namely that you are not *entitled* to feedback upon posting an answer (and/or that an upvote or downvote is sufficient feedback).

Comment: I would expect any moderator candidate to know the answer to this question.  Or any 20k+ rep user for that matter.  Meanwhile, this smells heavily like yet another assassination attempt aimed at the same moderator.  No idea what kind of war is raging in the [python] community.  Let's get this over with, since you are now an active combatant, do us all a favor and explain what the heck is going on and what it takes to get this resolved.

Comment: OP was last seen "Last seen Nov 11 at 6:10". I would have checked that before posting any more comments.

Comment: @HansPassant: the real issue here is that a moderator (who also was a moderator candidate, obviously) did something that he is supposed to help dealing with. I neither linked to the page with those comments nor put the name of the moderator in my question, so I fail to see why would you assume a "yet another assassination attempt". Note that this post includes a question, the answer to which I didn't find on this site. And FWIW, I don't know what war you are talking about.

Comment: @HansPassant: are you saying that he wasn't a moderator 19 hours ago?

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339062/automatic-deletion-of-comment-by-non-mod)  Also, this does smell passive/aggressive.

Comment: IMO: There is a very significant difference between asking for feedback and specifically asking for the OP to accept or up-vote an answer. Your question here conflates those two things and is characterizing statements as asking for an accept or up-vote which *very clearly* do not ask for the OP to accept or up-vote, but only request feedback of some sort. The fact that you do conflate them implies bias and/or an attempt to bias how readers of your question will interpret the comments you quoted/imaged. At least for me, your doing so significantly reduces your credibility.

Comment: My above comment is not intended to indicate my taking sides in whatever this ongoing issue is with a new mod. My comment is only intended to provide some feedback as to how *this question* appears.

Comment: I do agree that the third comment was probably a bit beyond what I would expect, but it/they don't reach into being *bad/wrong*. They may just reflect, and the last one explicitly states the existence of, other interaction between the OP and the person answering where the answer was specifically requested from that person, which could reasonably have set up an expectation of some feedback as to fulfilling the OP's request.

Answer (score 28):

> How should I handle such situations?

Flag.

Come on, you know this. You searched meta first, you've been around for a while, you know the basics. When you see noise, flag noise.

It's been sort of a joke among moderators (and others) for years that the first task a new moderator has is cleaning up all of the crap they themselves have posted over the years; it's funny because it's so often true: everyone posts crap sooner or later, and once elected the baleful eye of folks like yourself are gazing upon all of it.

So flag it. If the moderator responsible can't be objective (or just doesn't see the flags first), then someone else will handle it. And life will go on, because there are another thousand flags to handle, several hundred more comments to be deleted, before the day is over.

Comment: The point seems to be that the user is continuing *after* they became a mod, at which point they hopefully know better than to badger users, not that they have old stuff lying around.

Comment: I know what the point is, @davidism. The point is amusement for bored folks in room 6. But hey, let's keep up the pretense - is flagging *not* the correct answer in that situation still? By all means, post your own answer.

Comment: I'm about as tired as you are of this whole thing, and I've been dealing with it (as in the specific ongoing saga) longer. I'm definitely not amused though, if that's what you thought the point was. Based on the tone taken in response to these types of posts, I'm not really encouraged to post my own response.

Comment: What tone do you want, @davidism? "Oh look, it's the same folks playing conspiracy again - let's totally play along, because none of us have anything else to do here either?" If you got a complaint about a moderator, make it. If you want to help someone learn or perhaps even make 'em blush a bit when their peers bring it up, flag. If you just want to get rid of noise, flag. If you honestly don't know what to do with noise when you encounter it on Stack Overflow, search. If you're just bored, may I recommend a nice game of "Wordiest"?

Comment: And... Sorry; this isn't aimed at you specifically, @david. But you're not helping, and I don't want this to end in another week-long pointless argument over something trivial that could've easily been dealt with in 2 minutes with a lot more clarity and a lot less cloak-and-dagger if it'd been *anyone else on the site* involved. If this keeps up, folks ain't gonna listen if and when something really serious *does* happen; I've seen that before, and it ain't pretty.

Comment: I understand, we all get frustrated about these sorts of things, I'm not taking it personally. I don't think there's an intention to frame this as a conspiracy, nor is it done out of boredom. I guess what we should know is whether there's a tipping point at which pointing out more of this pattern of behavior will lead to anything besides a dismissal.

Comment: Of course, @davidism. The cardinal sins for moderation generally boil down to *not serving the community they're elected to serve.* A moderator who is callous, disruptive, unresponsive or duplicitous will be removed; this has happened in the past and sadly will probably happen again in the future. We watch every meta complaint, log every action, consider every email, lest such behavior be overlooked and become a poison... However, we're also [quite familiar with the antipatterns](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240500) that can confound such analysis.

Comment: @Shog9: I am very disappointed to see you dragging Room 6 into every discussion where someone who happens to be a regular of the room refers to that moderator, even indirectly. This post is not a collaborative work. I did *not* post this on behalf of the room, nor did I ask their input on the issue. Also, I see nothing amusing in this situation, so that's certainly *not* the reason this post exists.

Comment: I personally feel like the nature of this question isn't for amusement but to bring attention to it. There's clearly a view that there needs to be some sort of maturity required to be a moderator, of which, one in particular lacks which this question is trying to bring attention to, not for 'amusements' sake but how else would you make apparent something that isn't as definitive as abusing power? Is there another way to inform of what one believes to be inappropriate behaviour? Or rather we should see this more as a form of refining the election process?

Comment: You can consider it a form of training, @Shiri - lots of folks post stupid comments (and defend them stridently) without ever realizing the harm they cause in aggregate (see also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339062/automatic-deletion-of-comment-by-non-mod/339063#339063). So bringing them up *can* be useful. Of course, in this *particular* case the education is coming from the same little clique that's been fussing about everything since the election ended, so I'd take everything you read here with a grain of salt; there are some ulterior motives, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 13):

First time was probably okay, but after that, seems like it's a bit *noisy*.  I'd opt to flag the comments as "too chatty"; even with a downvote, this is still doing a bit too much.

Also, unless the original asker has left a comment, or this OP is posting these on the *question* (which is definitely not cool), the OP here is talking into a void; no one else gets notified about comments on an answer that no one else has commented or participated in.

Comment: Related: [What to do with user asking for upvote and accept?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297598/4099593)

Comment: As it turns out, these comments were actually *on the question itself*, rather than on the user's answer. vaultah didn't include that detail, and otherwise consciously avoided referring to the user by name, so I won't link to the question here, either. But wow. That makes this an entirely different level of inappropriate.

Comment: I mean considering that it's one of three newly elected moderators, anyone really wanting to find out will do be able to do so with less than 3 clicks.