# How to deal with an abusive user (answerer plus abuser to other answers)

Tags: discussion, abuse, specific-comment, specific-user

How to deal with an abusive user (answerer plus abuser to other answers)

The discussion have a reference to the question [Selenium: ElementNotVisibleException while trying to click the element with text as My Account onhttps://www.phptravels.net/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51510163/selenium-elementnotvisibleexception-while-trying-to-click-the-element-with-text).

There are total 6 answerers to this question who have provided an answer each to this question and one of the [answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9043475/rajagopalan) have went ahead and published the following comments for the *accepted answer* and possibly have downvoted the question and the other upvoted answers too, out of rage.

- Comment A:

> You should not accept an answer because someone is begging you. Please accept the answer which correctly addresses the issue. Element to be clicked or element to become visible nothing to do with your problem, your problem is in the wrong xpath formation. So don't accept the answer because people are begging you.

- Comment B:

> This answer doesn't deserve for the up-voting, this answer doesn't address the issue clearly. Read my answer to know the problem !

- Comment C:

> Please read my answer where I have detailed the problem clearly, the given xpath is not pointing out your targeted element, that's why it fails

So my question is:

- Doesn't the comments `CommentA` and `CommentB` violates [our "Be Nice" policy.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)?
- Earlier I have marked a couple of this concerned user's comments as *`rude and abusive`* and *`no longer needed`* and *`in need of moderator intervention`* which were deleted but is there any other way to deal with a *repeated offender*?

Comment: If you believe a user is rude or abusive as a rule, just flag any of their posts for moderator attention and explain the situation. No need to do anything else, or to bring the issues to meta, IMO.

Comment: The comments are being cleaned up at this moment, it seems.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't say those are "rude" comments, but certainly flaggable as "no longer needed". At least the first two, although the first comment does have some information that could be pertinent to the post.

Comment: I've flagged the lot of them as "no longer needed". The user in question is accusing the OP here of "begging" for an accept vote, which is a blatant lie. I'd argue that this is darn close to "harassment".

Comment: You should  flag comments and let a moderator handle it instead of calling out a user in a meta post. For the sake of transperancy, I have added a comment in the post in question to let them know the post is being brought up here

Comment: @yivi I don't think I have said anything wrong over there seriously. You may read my comments over there. I completely convinced that The answer that he has written has not address the issue. I used the word begging because he was urging the user to accept his answers faster. Can you please read the comments which I have written on his answer please ? You can understand what I mean here.

Comment: SO users tend to care a lot about the quality of the answers at the site.  If they stop caring then there is no point in keeping the site alive.  Calling this concern "abusive" is not appropriate.  Simply flagging these comments as "no longer needed" is all it takes.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: _"This answer doesn't deserve for the up-voting"_, _"You should not accept an answer because someone is begging you."_, That's __not acceptable__. Nor is pushing an OP to accept _your_ answer. Your comments on there weren't in line with SO's CoC.

Comment: @Rajagopalan What comment of mine were responding? I never said you _"said anything wrong_". I said I **didn't** believe your comments were rude, but that they weren't needed.

Comment: I am not pushing him to accept my answer , I have clearly written that the one who has the clear answer. The one that he has written doesn't address the issue of what OP is asking. He was urging the user to accept his answer as soon as he saw what I posted at was right. Please read those comments you will see what I meant.

Comment: @Rajagopalan: All i can see id ___you___ repeating over and over how the accepted answer shouldn't be accepted, and telling the OP to look at _your_ answer.

Comment: Accepting answer is not a competition I think , OP have the right to choose which answer helps him the most.

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't address the issue . In my opinion that's not exactly the problem of the OP. He doesn't want to listen, this is not the first time. Last time when I pointed out the mistake he down voted 4 of my answers. So it's the rage on his part of not accepting what others says .

Comment: @ARMAN yes correct, he is urging the user to accept faster as soon as I wrote what went wrong in his answer, please reread all the comments one by one.

Comment: @Rajagopalan If you've already had less than pleasant interactions with one user, I'd advise you to look for different questions to answer/comment to instead.

Comment: @yivi But why haven't I have the right to tell the truth that he is giving wrong answer but it's accepted. Why can't I? Please read the discussion once again . I did not say anything wrong. I said he is giving wrong answer to him, immediately after that he is writing to the OP to accept his answer.

Comment: @Rajagopalan It's simply a piece of advice. Looking for confrontations in SO is not the smartest idea. You do not want to be [this person](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @yivi there are many places he continue to give wrong answer , when I let him know he is writing the wrong answer he Looses his temper, he is not having the open mind set to receive what others are talking.

Comment: @Rajagopalan Just. Walk. Away. By engaging in this you are becoming part of the problem, not part of the solution.

Comment: don't know if you know but first comment could be deleted [by a single flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339063/839601) because it contains trigger-word "acc/ept"

Comment: @Rajagopalan rather than leave a comment, vote or mod flag. Whatever you do, don't argue or provoke. If you think a user is targeting you with revenge downvotes, please raise a custom mod flag on a post.

Comment: @YvetteColomb okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full discourse of the discussion:

[image]

***It's ok to say an answer is wrong and explain why***. However, that badgering under your answer is not acceptable. ***Leave one comment,  to continually berate the poster is not ok.***

It's ok to leave multiple comments if you're discussing an issue with someone and it's a mutual dialog, just not if one person really doesn't want to hear what the other has to say. Doesn't matter how right you are. Walk away.

1.

> You should not accept an answer because someone is begging you. Please accept the answer which correctly addresses the issue. Element to be clicked or element to become visible nothing to do with your problem, your problem is in the wrong xpath formation. So don't accept the answer because people are begging you.

This is not rude imo. A rude/abusive flag would be marked helpful, as it's not nice either. This type of comment is not needed and would be deleted with any flag raised.

2.

> This answer doesn't deserve for the up-voting, this answer doesn't address the issue clearly. Read my answer to know the problem !

This is rude.

3.

> Please read my answer where I have detailed the problem clearly, the given xpath is not pointing out your targeted element, that's why it fails

The best comment, the user should have made this one comment and walked away. Again, leave one comment, and if that doesn't seem to be effective, you can always walk away.

Next time, flag one of the comments for mod attention explaining what is happening and the mods can do a clean up and have a word with the other user if necessary.

***Flag any comment you think isn't appropriate for the site and walk away.***

Please note, asking people to upvote your answer is not particularly helpful and the exclamation marks make it worse.

Comment: Wow.  We've actually reached the point where stating that an answer is wrong is considered rude.  We've been moving in that direction of course, but I never thought the site would stray so far from it's desire for quality content that merely stating that an answer is wrong is considered inappropriate.  Is it really more important to prevent the author from being told that their answer is wrong than it is to help *everyone else in the world* who benefits from being informed of that.

Comment: @Servy: I think the problem is in _"doesn't __deserve__ for"_... That comment reads like _"This answer is baaad, my answer is goood, look at my answer!"_

Comment: @Cerbrus That doesn't make it rude.  You could certainly make an argument for "no longer needed".  Again, saying that an answer is bad isn't rude.  That people are saying as much is demonstrating that they don't care in the slightest about quality, which is ostensibly what is supposed to be different about this site.

Comment: @Servy it's the "This answer doesn't deserve for the up-voting," part. No one said you can't say an answer is wrong.

Comment: @Servy: Debatable, imo. I think it's at the same level as those people in front of a restaurant trying to drag you inside... I'd call it "rude".

Comment: @YvetteColomb That's saying that you don't think an answer is useful (since upvoting it is a way of indicating that it's not useful).  That's not rude.  People commenting on the value of a post, and as a result, how they think it should be voted on, is not *rude*.

Comment: @Servy: Depending on _how_ you say it. _"This answer sucks"_ is rude. _"This answer is wrong"_ isn't.

Comment: @Cerbrus precisely, it's the way it's worded. Of course someone can say, this is wrong and state why.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't see how it's debatable at all to say that expressing your opinion on the quality of a post is inherently rude.  And note that the "rude and abusive" flag isn't there just for "any action which violates social etiquette".  If you want to go with that analogy, proper etiquette would state that one of the rudest things you can do is *tell someone else that they have been rude*.  So by those standards *this answer* is unacceptably rude.

Comment: @Cerbrus But they didn't say, "this answer sucks".  They said, "this answer shouldn't be upvoted".

Comment: @YvetteColomb But that's what they *did*.  They said that the answer was wrong, and explained why, and you said it was rude.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Refusing to address serious problems with your answer pointed out by others is not something to be proud of.  You made a statement, it was demonstrably proven false.  Refusing to either acknowledge your mistake, or explain why you aren't, and just claiming to be right by your own authority, rather than any other reason, is not a good example to set.  And of course everyone else doesn't get to just have their way by virtue of being a mod.

Comment: @Servy: No, they said it doesn't _deserve_ upvotes.

Comment: @Cerbrus How is that any different?

Comment: @Servy: _"it was demonstrably proven false"_: debatable. _"your mistake"_: In your perception. I _often_ disagree with Yvette, but Servy, you're being just as stubborn here.

Comment: @Servy: How is _"This answer doesn't deserve upvotes"_ not different from _"This answer is wrong"_?

Comment: @Cerbrus I find it ironic that a moderator saying, "I'm going to refuse to even acknowledge your points and will assert that I'm right without supporting my position" is the one who's *not* being stubborn.

Comment: @Servy: ___"just as stubborn"___. Equal. The same.

Comment: @Cerbrus I assumed you were referring responding to my response to you, and were therefore saying that, "this answer shouldn't be upvoted" and "it doesn't deserve upvotes" are materially different.  As for a post being wrong versus not meriting upvotes, they're not saying the same thing, but I see no difference in their appropriateness.  A post can be "not useful" for reasons other than being wrong, but I don't see how the difference is relevant to whether or not it's rude.

Comment: @Servy: The "shouldn't be upvoted" is an example you made up. It's not relevant here. I agree it's similar to _"doesn't deserve upvotes"_. But it's quite different from "This answer is wrong".

Comment: @Cerbrus How is the difference relevant to whether or not the comment is appropriate?

Comment: @Servy: Because this whole discussion started with _you_ claiming: _"We've actually reached the point where stating that an answer is wrong is considered rude."_ No. The rudeness is in the _"doesn't deserve upvotes"_. Stating a answer is "wrong" is fine. That's where the difference matters.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'll ask again, *how is the difference between those statements relevant to whether or not they are rude*?  As I've mentioned, they have a few minor differences (an answer can not merit upvotes for a broader range of reasons than just being wrong).  What differences between those two statements *are relevant to whether or not they are rude*?

Comment: Something being "wrong" isn't subjective. Something not "deserving" upvotes is. If you can't see the difference between the two, there's no point in me trying to explain it (even more)

Comment: @Cerbrus The correctness of an answer can sometimes be subjective, but anyway, a criticism of an answer being subjective doesn't make it rude.  You're not required to make entirely objectively verifiable criticisms of an answer.  Again, I have mentioned that there are certainly differences between the two statements in meaning.  I don't see any difference in the appropriateness or rudeness between them.  You haven't explain the difference (in rudeness) between them *at all*.  You've continually brought up some differences in meaning *that have no effect on how rude they are*.

Comment: @Servy: _"that have no effect..."_ Maybe not in your perception, but yours is not the only one. I'm just saying, I can understand why a rude flag on that would be validated.

Comment: @Cerbrus So the only reason you can put forth for why it's rude is that you say so, and nothing else?

Comment: @Servy So the only reason you can put forth for why it's not rude is that you say so, and nothing else?

Comment: @Cerbrus So one needs to demonstrably prove that every single thing anyone says ever *isn't* rude in order for it to not be deleted for being rude?  In that case, every single comment that you've ever posted is rude.  Prove that they aren't if they aren't actually rude.  The burden of proof is one the one accusing it of being rude.  Not on anyone else to prove that it isn't.

Comment: So, my opinion and a moderator's opinion, are meaningless if I can't _prove_ that something is rude? How do you even prove rudeness? That's silly.

Comment: @Servy I want to thank you for understanding me. He hasn't brought up the whole conversation here, He took it from the place something went wrong. At the very first of comment of mine, I clearly explained where he went wrong, he hasn't even given any attention to me, he rushed into OP to accept his answer immediately and then the following three comments were followed.

Comment: @Cerbrus It's not *entirely* meaningless.  It doesn't mean a whole lot.  I suppose "prove" is not the proper term here, but you should be able to provide some supporting arguments for the position beyond just the mere statement that you think it's rude.  And of course lots of other people think it's *not* rude.

Comment: @Servy: "*you should be able to provide some supporting arguments for the position beyond just the mere statement that you think it's rude.*" OK, here's one argument: repeated haranguing someone is rude. Posting a single comment explaining that the post is wrong is fine. Posting *multiple* such comments when others are not responding to your earlier comment is rude. That makes every comment after the first increasingly rude.

Comment: @NicolBolas They posted one comment to say that the answer is wrong, and another comment responding to a later comment saying that they shouldn't be telling the OP to accept answers.  So the only additional comment is responding to an earlier comment.  They also posted similar comments *to another person* (the question author).  So you're arguing that saying the same thing to two different people is inherently rude.

Comment: @Servy: And in *every single* such comment, the answerer is getting pinged, whether they're @ mentioned or not. So the "This answer doesn't deserve for the up-voting" is simply belaboring the point.

Comment: @NicolBolas So you're saying that the comment you just posted is rude, because you're replying to me on Yvette's answer?  Again, several of those comments shouldn't have been posted, and merited deletion, but that doesn't make them *rude*.

Answer (score 3):

It's not appropriate of you to be posting comments to try to get the author of the question to accept your answer.  It would have been better if that commentor would have flagged your comments, rather than commenting on them to explain why that's not appropriate behavior here.  Once your comments were eventually deleted, *their* comments became obsolete and merited deletion for pointing out problems with your deleted comments.

Posting a comment on someone else's answer to say that they should read your answer is just redundant.  We don't need everyone telling everyone else to read their answers instead.  Feel free to flag as "no longer needed".

The third comment, summarizing why the answer is wrong and directing users to their answers *for further information and details* is appropriate and useful.  Similarly to how link only answers are evaluated, this is a comment that is useful in it's own right, but also includes direction to further reading elsewhere.  This comment is appropriate, and should not have been removed (at least not until your answer was edited to address the problems it raises).

Comment: hey this answer says the same thing mine does. Come and read my answer and accept and upvote it!! This one doesn't deserve upvotes, it's a copy of mine!! (now is this rude?)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot Yvette provided, DebanjanB only asked for upvotes once, and explicitly mentioned "any answer" to be the target of said votes. (That's meh, but not necessarily wrong). He doesn't seem to have asked for an "accept" vote, so that seems to be misinformation from Rajagopalan.

Comment: @YvetteColomb No, your comment isn't rude, it's just demonstrably wrong.  I'm more than happy to explain why it's wrong, rather than feeling the need to flag your comment as being rude due to an inability or unwillingness to let my arguments stand on their own merits.  While both of us come to the same conclusion as to which of the comments should be deleted, we disagree (strongly) as to why.  This is a big deal.  A comment being considered "rude" is *very* different from a comment being considered appropriate, but now obsolete.

Comment: The main difference is that we don't want people going around flagging comments pointing out problems *that have not yet been resolved*, even though we're okay with them (correctly) flagging criticisms that have since been resolved.  Additionally, there can be consequences for "rude" comments, beyond just deletion.  That's not true of obsolete comments.

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't see how someone asking for upvotes versus accepts is a relevant difference.  Neither is appropriate.  The comment should be flagged and deleted regardless.

Comment: My point is that Rajagopalan was grossly exaggerating how DebanjanB was behaving. This answer seems to be (partially) based on Rajagopalan's statements.

Comment: @Cerbrus Saying acceptance, rather than upvotes (especially given that the answer was in fact accepted, not upvoted) is a minor mistake.  I don't really see it as an exaggeration, merely an understandable slip of the tongue.

Comment: @Servy tbh I think that we are being tied up in knots about what we can and cannot say. I disagreed with your interpretation of my answer.

Comment: @Servy: I disagree. _"I used the word begging because he was urging the user to accept his answers faster."_ <-- He wasn't confusing _"accepting"_ with _"upvoting"_ there. That sentence is "fake news". It's a lie to make the OP here look bad.

Comment: @YvetteColomb Yes, you're quite right that the issue that we cannot agree on is what is or is not appropriate for people to say.  You've said that you disagree with my interpretation of your answer, but not why it's not a valid interpretation of your answer (or edited the answer to make it clear that it cannot be interpreted that way).  I feel that it's *very* important that people be able to comment on an answer to say that it's not useful and why, and not be accused of being rude as a way of silencing valid criticism.

Comment: @Cerbrus But it's *not* a lie.  He *was* urging the OP to upvote his answer.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, ___upvote___. But Rajagopalan is claiming he's demanding to have his answer ___accepted___. That's demonstrably incorrect. And he only asked _once_ to have _helpful_ answers upvoted. That's not that bad, and certainly didn't warrant Rajagopalan's multiple comments.

Comment: @Servy Honestly, I think you're blowing that a little out of proportion. Yes, he suggested upvoting. He, however, suggested upvoting _an_ answer _that was helpful_ to a new(er) user. He did it once, did not specify only his answer, and explicitly said _any_ answer. Now, if it was only his answer he said should be upvoted, I'd agree with you all day. But he didn't, he said _any_ answer.

Comment: @Cerbrus So you *do* think that they simply mixed up the terms "upvote" and accept, and your statement that that's *not* the problem with the comment is in fact wrong.  Good to know.  Asking *once* for the OP to upvote your answer is still not appropriate.  Telling them that they can also upvote other answers if they want too doesn't make the comment any more appropriate.  I agreed that they shouldn't have commented on it. They should have flagged the comment. They didn't comment to the answer author on the issue twice, they commented once to the answer author, and once to the question author.

Comment: ... What? Where are you getting that nonsense from? Now you're just deliberately misinterpreting me.

Comment: @Kendra A user that's been around for *nine years* is new?  I didn't realize I was still a new user.  Telling someone to upvote your answer doesn't suddenly become appropriate just because you later tell them to also upvote other people's answers.

Comment: @Cerbrus Are you accusing the user of *maliciously* using the term "accept" instead of "upvote", rather than *mistakenly* using the other term then?  I don't know how else I could misinterpret your statement that he wasn't confusing the two terms, later followed by the statement that they used the wrong term.  If you're accusing them of *intentionally* using the wrong term for some malicious purpose, you're going to need to provide some support for why they'd do that and why you think they did it.

Comment: @Servy: "*you're going to need to provide some support for why they'd do that and why you think they did it.*" If someone repeatedly makes the same mistake over and over (has he has done in the comment thread on this question *and* once in the comments on the answer under discussion), you have to at least consider the possibility that it's not a mistake. Especially since he got it right in one of his comments in that answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas Consider that by the time they commented on the issue here the original comment had been deleted.  They may have also simply misread the comment (which would explain them consistantly getting it wrong).  But regardless, I don't see how it *matters* whether they were asking for an accept or an upvote.  I don't see what motivation anyone might have for accusing someone of asking for one when they knew they were asking for the other.

Comment: Well, @Servy, you’ve shown how people are capable of consistently mis-interpreting comments, so I guess that, in theory, it’s possibly he _repeatedly_ mistakingly accused the OP of solliciting an accept vote... Or he’s just sour because his answer didn’t get accepted. Wouldn’t be the first time.

Comment: @Cerbrus What motivation is there to *intentionally* use the wrong term?  You're accusing someone of making a mistake maliciously, a rather serious allegation, rather than unintentionally, for the sole reason that they made the same mistake twice?  And that despite the fact that if the mistake was misreading the comment, not mis-typing it, would certainly happen every time.  And now you're accusing them of being upset that an incorrect answer is accepted just because it's not theirs, and not because an incorrect answer is accepted, something which should make *anyone* upset.

Comment: Yea, that pretty much sums up my accusations. Ta.