# Can Stack Overflow users beg for upvotes/acceptance in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I have see many users begging to upvote/accept in comments (either in the answer or in the original question).

For example, a few moments ago I saw comments saying *"feel free to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you"*; and a few days ago I have seen another one saying something like *"Please accept/upvote my answer"*.

I want to know which kind (if any) of begging is valid.

Comment: Users can beg, but it is not great form. I guess that occasional begging is fine, but insistent and recurrent begging less so. Even then, those comments are ripe to be flagged "no longer needed" and deleted summarily.

Comment: Better yet: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298579/is-it-greedy-to-ask-newbies-to-not-forget-an-upvote-if-they-find-the-answer-us

Comment: On a slightly related note: I just left a comment under a "It works. Tx" comment from someone not having accepted *any* answer for *six* freakin' years.