# What did I do wrong here? Why did the vote down occur to my answer, while the other gained 2?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes

In reference to [TypeError: rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.throw is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602511/typeerror-rxjs-webpack-imported-module-2-observable-throw-is-not-a-function/50602550#50602550)

My answer gave the solution, and the discussion below specified the exact import. However, it was given a vote down, and the other answer has been voted up in it's place.

I have since edited in the missing import as perhaps it being in the comments of the answer was insufficient.

Did I do anything particularly wrong here? It's only the one vote, but I can't actually see anything that I particularly did that was deserving of it, and would like to avoid it happening again!

Comment: Alternatively, let me know what I've done wrong here by proceeding to ask what I've done wrong on the main site. StackOverflow's culture is a little tricky to understand.

Comment: one vote can be : a miss click, a wrong vote, someone who don't like you, someone who want to try the downvote, etc etc etc ... so no need to care a lot about *one* downvote

Comment: Offhand, I don't see too much difference between your answer and the original besides age so I can't tell you exactly why. It may be that it's effectively the same as the previous answer with a little more context. Either way, it's only one downvote

Comment: It's only a downvote. If we came to meta to try to guess why everyone voted, we'd talk about that and nothing else, and even then cover only a very small subset of votes. And finally, we aren't mindreaders, nobody can't tell you why anyone voted the way they did  but the voter.

Comment: All fair. May have taken it a little too seriously, what with the giant red mark in my profile and all. Shall take it in stride and move on.

Comment: It contains a bit of fluff, which might lead to downvotes. A general tip: share the code first, then share the link below it, to make the link support the code, and not the other way round. Also, asking for someone to accept your own answer can be considered bad form. See things like [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298579/7296893)

Comment: by the way you have edited your answer to add the import solution and initially your code wasn't working and the other answer provided the solution before you

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just assuming the downvotes that you get aren't actually an indication of the quality of your posts isn't healthy.  You should always assume that any downvotes you get are because the voter sincerely felt that your question wasn't useful, and do your best to try to find and correct whatever problems may have caused that.  That's how you improve and post better content, not by just assuming you're infallable and never even trying to improve your posts.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, I mentioned above that I had edited it to include the import, although the import itself was in the answer comments.

Comment: @Servy am not assuming this, I am highlighting potential reasons ... Since it's *one* downvote and you are sure about the quality and the content of your answer  so no need to bother yourself ... if you get more downvotes then you should think about.

Comment: @erikvonasmuth Duly noted with regards asking to mark as the answer. Didn't honestly consider linking the reason the error was occurring as "fluff" content, although in retrospect it's not immediately the fix that users would be looking for.

Comment: @TemaniAfif You say that you're not assuming it, and then *just repeated the exact same assumption that you're claiming you're not making*.  Again, you're claiming that you should just ignore downvotes on your post and not "bother  yourself" trying to figure out what might be wrong with the posts and how they could be improved.  That's a *bad idea*.  You shouldn't just ignore that feedback.

Comment: @MetaPyroxia The fluff imo are very subtle things. _Try using_ adds uncertainty, just _Use_ is sufficient. The link is good, but starting an answer with a link is risky, people might think it's link-only. The long comment chain also doesn't help.

Comment: @MetaPyroxia comments aren't supposed to hold part of the answer. If the downvote happened before you edited the missing important in, I would guess that you got downvoted for providing an answer that wouldn't run

Comment: It is a typical "fastest gun in the west" outcome.  You posted an answer less than 2 minutes after the question was asked, but did not know enough yet to answer it correctly.  Lots of back-and-forth in the comments was next.  Then the other SO user showed up late, knew everything necessary to answer it correctly.  FGITW is a tricky game to play, you'll easily shoot your left foot.

Comment: Damn...[my cat has been at the keyboard again!](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/how-can-i-keep-my-cat-off-my-keyboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have since edited in the missing import as perhaps it being in the comments of the answer was insufficient.

It's only one downvote, so of course we can't be sure, but this is probably it. If someone came by and tried your answer without reading the comments they might have been frustrated enough to downvote you when they had to keep looking for a solution because your answer didn't "just work." (The newer answer gives the missing piece at the top, so it does just work.)

Comment: I've always regarded the comments as being part of the answer but that's probably absolutely it. Just wanted some clarification around that really.

Comment: @MetaPyroxia I've always considered them a part of the post, but you have to consider that not everyone is going to have the patience to read them, particularly if there's any back-and-forth discussion. It's best to edit the answer to include all the relevant details that come out in that discussion.

Comment: "I've always regarded the comments as being part of the answer"... you want to change that perception. Comments are, by design, ephemeral. They can go away without warning, whether you like it or not. Assume they *will* go away. Information that's not *in the answer* may as well not be there.